# where did 'resolved.xml.xml` file disappear?

Tags: sbt

after changing the `sbt.version` in the `build.properties` to `1.3.x`, i've found out that the `resolved.xml.xml` files, which were created after running `sbt compile` are not created anymore.  i'm using those files to re-create the project's structure and dependencies tree.
is there any equivalent to those files in the new SBT version?
yes, i'm familiar with `sbt-dependency-graph` plugin, but i want to avoid using external solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable the integrated coursier to get the old behaviour back:

```
ThisBuild / useCoursier := false
```